# TFS Build Process: The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2013

I am using TFS2010 build process and it is failing with the following error

The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

but when I build the solution through VS IDE it is building ok without error and the code work ok. Note that I have a reference to System.web in my project. and I don't have access to the build machine

I am using VS2013. TFS 2010.

Any advice please?

Comment: Can you see `System.Web` listed as reference in the XAML?

Comment: Is .NET installed on the build machine?

Comment: You have the reference in _your_ Project, but how about the Project on the server?

Comment: I don't have access to the server but I know for sure that other projects used httpUtility and it build ok on the same build server

Comment: Yes, but they were other projects.

Answer (score 1):

You must update setup of your framework on your build machine, this assembly is missed on your GAC.
Or use GacUtil on remote desktop on your build machine

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same issue today. This is what I had to do:

1. Log into the build machine
2. Fire up Visual Studio
3. Map and get latest of the branch
4. Attempt the build local from that build machine
5. Get same error, add reference to the offending dll, check in changes.